# Daisy Chaining Elvis Operators?

Tags: kotlin, nullable, kotlin-null-safety

This is sorta ugly:

```
override var x1: Double = 0.0 //x-coordinate for object
    get() =
        if(hasParent) { //if there is no parent, we can't have an x coord anyway - nowhere to draw this object
            if (hasPrev) { //we won't always have a previous event, thus the other branch
                prev!!.x2 + parent!!.mEventSpacing
            } else {
                parent!!.mEventStartX
            }
        } else {
            field
        }
```

Is it possible to replace it with something like the following?

```
override var x1: Double = 0.0
    get() = (prev?.x2 + parent?.mEventSpacing) ?: parent?.mEventStartX ?: field
```

The logic is obviously not right there, but is there something close to this? Or would it require some serious fandangling to do something that simple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that `hasParent = parent != null` and `hasPrev = prev != null`.
Also assume `parent` and `prev` are defined as `val`, not `var` in the `if` or `when` statements because I don't like to add `!!` many times.

What you are doing is, using `when` expression:

```
override var x1: Double = 0.0 //x-coordinate for object
    get() = when {
        parent != null && prev != null -> prev.x2 + parent.mEventSpacing
        parent != null && prev == null -> parent.mEventSpacing
        parent == null -> field
    }
```

You can use the combination of `?.` operator and `let` function (refer to [Safe Calls](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) section):

```
override var x1: Double = 0.0 //x-coordinate for object
    get() =
        parent?.let { pr -> prev?.let { pv -> pv.x2 + pr.mEventSpacing } ?: pr.mEventSpacing } ?: field
```

`let` function executes the parameter block whose parameter is what called `let`, and return the last expression in the parameter block.

For example, `1.let { it + 2 }` is `3`.

`x?.let` executes the `let` function if `x` is not null.
i.e., `x?.let { ... }` is the same as `if (x != null) x.let { ... } else null)`.

Here,

if `parent == null`, then
`parent?.let { pr -> prev?.let { pv -> pv.x2 + pr.mEventSpacing } ?: pr.mEventSpacing }` is just `null`.

if `parent != null`, then
`parent?.let { pr -> prev?.let { pv -> pv.x2 + pr.mEventSpacing } ?: pr.mEventSpacing }` is the same as `prev?.let { pv -> pv.x2 + parent!!.mEventSpacing } ?: parent!!.mEventSpacing`

You can shorten this. if `prev == null`, then `prev.x2` can be treated as `0`. So

```
override var x1: Double = 0.0 //x-coordinate for object
    get() =
        parent?.let { pr -> (prev?.let { pv -> pv.x2 } ?: 0) + pr.mEventSpacing } ?: field
```

You can further shorten this by using `it` in the inner `let` function.

```
override var x1: Double = 0.0 //x-coordinate for object
    get() =
        parent?.let { pr -> (prev?.let { it.x2 } ?: 0) + pr.mEventSpacing } ?: field
```

Also, you can use combination of `run` and `let`. (Google `kotlin run` or `kotlin run vs let` if you don't know it.)

```
override var x1: Double = 0.0 //x-coordinate for object
    get() =
        parent?.run { (prev?.let { it.x2 } ?: 0) + mEventSpacing } ?: field
```

But I think using `when` is the eastest to understand.

---

Well, if `parent` and `prev` were defined as `var`, using `when` expression with `!!` can raise a NPE, whereas using `?.let`, `?.run`, and `?:` will never raise a NPE in a multi-core device. To prevent this, you can define local `val`s with the current values in the getter function so that you will never need to use the `!!` operator.

Comment: Also, "?.let, ?.run, and ?: will never raise a NPE in a multi-core device." Why is that? Is there some literature you can point me to?

Comment: @LSM07 Of course, using another null variable in `run` or `let` functions can raise a NPE. What I mean is that, if you use `var` with null comparison (e.g. `if (parent != null)` and then use `!!` operator, you can get a NPE. What happens is this: Core 1 executes null comparison like `if (parent != null)`. Core 2 exeuctes assignment like `parent = null` in another thread, another code. Core 1 excutes the statement inside the not-null if block like `println(parent!!.mEventSpaing)`. Then you get a NPE.

Comment: @LSM07 There are ways to prevent this. First way: You can assign the `var` variable to local `val` variable, and then use `val` variable afterwards in the function. It will not be changed into `null` because it is `val`. Second way: You can use `varVariable?.let { ... }`. If `varVariable` were `null`, then the result will be `null` without a NPE. If `varVariable` were not `null`, then the parameter of the block, which is `it` variable in the block, will be assigned to not-null value, and `it` will not be changed in another thread, so it can prevent a NPE.